# Python Getting Specific JSON values from AWS GuardDuty

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've written some code on AWS Lambda and I am trying to extract the IPs from GuardDuty's findings. I have gotten the FindingIds okay, but when I try and extract the IP address I get the following error:

> {   "errorMessage": "list indices must be integers or slices, not
>   str",   "errorType": "TypeError",   "stackTrace": [
>       [
>         "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
>         38,
>         "lambda_handler",
>         "print(loadFindings['Findings']['Resource']['NetworkInterfaces']['PublicIp'])"
>       ]   ] }

My full code is below so far:

```
import json
import boto3
from pprint import pprint # Pretty-print for displaying the JSON nicely.

#pprint(listOfFindings)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('guardduty') # Creating the client.
    Det_ID = '5ab1b6808e98faaabd947a01af9ed970' # Setting the Detect ID for GD.
    response = client.list_findings(DetectorId=Det_ID) # Gathering all findings... Need to filter.
    findings = json.dumps(response) # Dumping the JSON findings
    listOfFindings = json.loads(findings) # Making them into a readable format for Python.
    # print("Here's the IDs!",listOfFindings['FindingIds'],"\n\n\n") # Printing all Finding IDs.

    idPosition=0
    idList = []
    for id in listOfFindings['FindingIds']: # Looping through all the Finding IDs. 
        #print("\n\n\nNumber", x, listOfFindings['FindingIds'][x]) # Prints all the Finding Ids separated.
        idList.append(listOfFindings['FindingIds'][idPosition])
        idPosition+=1

    # print("TEST") - Debugging.
    # print(idList) - Debugging.

    findingsList = []
    position = 0
    for ids in idList:
        # print(idList[position])
        stringFindingId = str(idList[position])
        #stringFindingId = idList[position]
        allFindings = client.get_findings(
            DetectorId=Det_ID,
            FindingIds=[
                stringFindingId,])
        dumpFindings = json.dumps(allFindings)
        loadFindings = json.loads(dumpFindings)
        # findingsList.append(loadFindings)
        print(loadFindings['Findings']['Resource']['NetworkInterfaces']['PublicIp']) # BROKEN HERE
        position += 1
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a sample of `loadFindings ` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/guardduty.html#GuardDuty.Client.get_findings) show that the value for `'Findings'` is a list of dictionaries. So either just use `allFindings['Findings'][0]` (if there's only one item in the list) or loop over `allFindings['Findings']`.

By the way this code is pointless:

```
    dumpFindings = json.dumps(allFindings)
    loadFindings = json.loads(dumpFindings)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: How come the code is pointless? It returns a JSON dict which needs to be converted to Python processable. Still get the same error.

Comment: @SamPitman it just returns a dictionary, I don't know where you're getting the JSON idea from. More generally, `json.loads(json.dumps(x))` is always going to equal `x`.

Comment: My bad, saw some other guys doing that, but appears they have no clue what they're on about! Two quick questions what is '[0]' needed for after '['Findings']' and this line of code isn't working: pprint(allFindings['Findings'][0]['Resource']['InstanceDetails']['NetworkInterfaces']['PublicIp']) - Works without ['PublicIp'], but won't work with it.

Comment: `allFindings['Findings']` is a list, `allFindings['Findings'][0]` is the first element of that list. `allFindings[...]['NetworkInterfaces']` is again a list (note the `[` before the `{` in the response syntax in the docs, or just print things to see what they are) which you should loop over to find the correct interface.

Comment: Can't seem to retrieve ['PublicIp'] - response is here http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/guardduty.html#GuardDuty.Client.get_findings

Comment: (1) I gave that link myself in the answer (2) "Can't seem to retrieve" doesn't tell me anything. Do you understand what I said? Did you loop over the list? What did you try and what went wrong?

Comment: `findingList = ['9ab1b68a7053ebe5917b0e874dc13476','30b1b91a03d74e9f2434391cdc303e2a','1ab1b91a03d6aa437595648875251097']
    #print(len(findingList))
    position = 0
    for i in range(len(findingList)):
        print(findingList[position])
        allFindings = client.get_findings(
            DetectorId=Det_ID,
            FindingIds=[
                findingList[position]])
        pprint(allFindings['Findings'][position]['Resource']['InstanceDetails']['NetworkInterfaces'][position]['PublicIp'])
        position += 1`

Comment: Tried the following code above ^. Can retrieve PublicIp if position is set to 0, but if not, it will produce this error: IndexError: list index out of range. Really can't see what I'm doing wrong, probably a very silly issue there. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: You're looping over the findings. There's no reason there'd be as many findings as network interfaces on a single instance.

Comment: I see! Sorry not very familiar with JSON and how it works within Python so I'm getting super confused even though it doesn't seem too hard. How would I go about retrieving 'PublicIp' for a list of FindingIDs?

Comment: There's no JSON involved here, it's just lists and dictionaries. There's a list of network interfaces, and each one can have a public IP. Maybe there's only one element in that list and you can just use `[0]`. Maybe there's several and you have to loop over the list and find which network interface satisfies some criteria. Maybe if you check now the list will only have one element but some other times there'll be several. I can't walk you through every detail of this. I think you may have chosen a task that you're not ready to tackle at your skill level.

Comment: Completely understand now, think I was having a bit of brain fog. Appreciate the help! :)